# Saving a Swift array of Strings and URLs to NSUserDefaults results in crash, why/how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, nsurl

I have a Swift array. Each item in this array is a "sub array" of two items, a String and a URL. So the Swift type is `[[Any]]`, and could look like this for instance:

```
[ ["hlors", URL(string: "https://google.com")!], ["qtvmr", URL(string: "https://bing.com"!)] ]
```

When I try to save this to NSUserDefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: DefaultsKeys.subredditIcons)
```

I get the following error:

> [User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object ( ... ) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key TestKey123

What am I doing wrong here? NSUserDefaults should be able to save URLs and Strings, right? There's nothing here exotic?

Comment: Check the documentation of [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults). `URL` (or `NSURL`) is not listed in the plist compatible types - `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @OOPer What? There's literally a setURL method on NSUserDefaults. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414194-seturl?language=objc

Comment: Unfortunately, the existence of that method does not mean `UserDefaults` can contain `URL`. The method converts `NSURL` to one of the plist compatible types (`NSString` or `NSData`) and store it to the `UserDefaults`, but no other methods, unless clearly documented, would not make such conversion. You may need to convert your URLs yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414067-setobject):

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and
>   NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

It seems like the simplest solution, in your case, would be just to store the URLs' string values, or to use `NSKeyedArchiver`.

As you point out in your comment there is a method for `setUrl:forKey`, though if you read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414194-seturl) and check the "Discussion" section you can see that the method turns the URL into a string to archive, and then does the opposite when retrieving the object later.  This would not be true when the URL is in the contents of an Array or Dictionary, per the above.